# wordpress 4.9.6 visual editor adding span code

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, editor

Many have this issue but no solution. Wordpress 4.9.6 adds span code to editor when clicking the visual editor tab. Created an exact copy of wordpress buildout folder and database and the copy site does not have this issue.
Why would an exact copy not have same issues?

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being CloudFront. Added an exception to cloudfront and that fixed the issue.